# Laptop for light video editing, programming etc

Tags: laptop, gaming, development, video-editing

I need a laptop that will cope with light video editing, software development, and maybe a bit of gaming if I have time. I regularly have 30+ tabs open in Chrome, with multiple Word / Excel / Outlook instances open and run disk intensive downloads frequently.

My budget is £875 (GBP) including UK VAT absolute max.

Needs to have

- An Intel Core i7 5th Gen or greater
- At least 256GB harddrive, SSD preferred but can be an m.2 of lesser capacity as long as it has a second HDD
- FHD (1920x1080) resolution or better
- 8GB of RAM or more

Would be nice to have (not vital)

- 15" or larger Screen
- 8 or more hours of battery life on general computing, not intensive stuff clearly
- A dedicated GPU

Bear in mind I have built a PC before, and if a cheaper laptop is upgradeable within my budget, im happy to do that, such as buy a bigger internal hdd or RAM with the laptop all within the £875 (GBP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your requirements, I'd recommend Dell's [New Inspiron 15 5000 (5567)](http://www.dell.com/uk/p/inspiron-15-5567-laptop/pd?oc=cn55717&model_id=inspiron-15-5567-laptop) which goes for about **£799 + VAT and delivery**. From personal experience, Dell's laptops tend to be decently robust and are of good quality.

---

***Reasons for Recommendation:***

*Meets All of your Requirements:*

- 7th Gen Kaby Lake i7-7500U @ 2.7GHz
- 256GB SSD
- 1920x1080 FHD Display
- 16GB DDR4-2400 MHz

*Meets of your non-Vital Requirements:*

- 15.6" Anti-Glare Display
- [7hrs 35min run time on battery while browsing.](http://laptopmedia.com/review/dell-inspiron-15-5567-review-a-good-all-rounder-for-work-multimedia-and-even-gaming/)
- Dedicated GPU - AMD Radeon R7 M445

---

SSD upgrades are possible, however they may not be within your budget since most larger capacity SSDs cost more than £75.

[image: 5567]

Comment: Great Thanks, I went with this, hopefully it will arrive soon! I will use the rest of my budget to upgrade it to Windows 10 Pro!